# checkmk monitor hdd health with SMART for windows hosts

Tags: monitoring, nagios, check-mk

Hi I need to monitor the Health of hdd and ssds of windows Hosts. I try to use checkmk to do this. I found this:
https://checkmk.com/de/integrations/openhardwaremonitor_smart

But no tutorial or docu for this. Agent is installed and works. But How can I add the smart value check for this host?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Maybe this [Checkmk forum post](https://forum.checkmk.com/t/probe-to-scan-s-m-a-r-t-status-on-windows-systems/17112) can help you achieve what you are trying to do.